# Audio quirks after pavucontrol install on i3wm

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, pavucontrol

Have been experimenting with i3wm on a Ubuntu 22.04 system.

Installed `pavucontrol` on i3wm to control sound settings.  After moving back to GNOME, adjusting via the Settings menu (Settings->Sound->Output) no longer impacted how sound was output (eg, opening up the Sound menu and changing output device to 'Analog Output' didn't send audio to specified device).

Practically, the workaround I've found when audio 'resets' is to select one of 'Speakers - Built-in Audio' or 'HDMI/Displayport', which does seem receptive to change within the Settings menu, and thereafter changing to desired output device (eg, USB out, BT headphones, etc).  For some reason, moving to the next video in YouTube `resets` audio and I need to go through the process again, but listening to Spotify and moving song to song doesn't have the same effect.

**Any thoughts on how to debug this?**  Have included output devices below:

```
chris@chris-X1C6:~$ pactl list short sources
2   alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo   module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
3   alsa_input.usb-046d_HD_Pro_Webcam_C920_F413D27F-02.analog-stereo    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 32000Hz   RUNNING
5   alsa_input.usb-Generic_ThinkPad_Dock_USB_Audio-00.analog-stereo module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
14  alsa_input.usb-FiiO_DigiHug_USB_Audio-01.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
30  alsa_output.usb-Generic_ThinkPad_Dock_USB_Audio-00.analog-stereo.monitor    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
40  alsa_output.usb-FiiO_DigiHug_USB_Audio-01.analog-stereo.monitor module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
82  alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
```